# Kibana dashboard reflects wrong data counts on next day

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to create heatmap in Kibana dashboard.
I have created the Database view which is fetching correct data. I have verified all the inputs manually. So, my database view is correct and reflects data correctly every day.
But when I draw the graph in the Kibana using the elastic search index, ***for newly drawn graph count reflects correctly*** and all data matches with the database view response. ***BUT the next day when I open the dashboard the data and the count everything will wrong .*** [timerange will be correct]

Can someone please help me with these issues, I have been stuck with this for quite some time now.

Things I have tries:

1. I have set the correct time frame and verified the time range in dashboard and in my database view and in logstash conf file .
2. I have set the refresh interval as 20 seconds.
   [image]
3. Verified the output of the logstash conf file using the below command : `sudo -u logstash /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash --path.settings /etc/logstash -t /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/index_visitor_analytics_view_demo_server.conf`

The entries that are coming in the dashboard are not present in the Logstash output, but they are just present in the database. My database view is not picking that entry, nor my logastash conf output is showing that entry but it appears in the Discover tab and Dashboard tab of Kibana.
In the below image it should be 11 entries instead it is showing 17 entries.
[image]

Also When I try to get the response fromGET /index_visitor_analytics_view_demo_server/_search?pretty
I am getting correct result count , but just in dashboard we see wrong result

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like duplicated data to me. Can you please check distinct count of each document?

```
#go to dev tools
GET your_index_name/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Document.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I got the output like this :{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 19,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "NAME" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [ ]
    }
  }
}   and also its not duplicate data, i have verified the ids, all IDs are unique which is correct, but it's just showing some wrong ids also.

Comment: The output is empty try with a correct field name